# Hypothesis tests on 2-dimensional panel data w/ 1 characteristic?

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, panel-data

I have a 2-dimensional panel data set with one characteristic looking along these lines:

```
individual | year | BMI
1            2005   25.3
1            2006   25.4
1            2007   24.1
2            2005   22.9
2            2006   22.1
2            2007   21.1
...
```

I also have annual values for another external variable V for the years 2005 - 2007, and I'd like to investigate whether there's a correlation between people's BMI and V. In particular, I have a hypothesis that the true correlation is > 0 that I want to test.

My question is, can I test this by constructing a "time series" that pairs each BMI value with the value of V for the given year and use Pearson's r for the hypothesis test and correlation coefficients? Why or why not? If I do that, are the results at all useful? If not, what are the alternatives that are rather simple to perform?

I'll clarify what I mean by constructing the time series. Assume V is 1.1, 2.2 and 3.3 for 2005 - 2007, respectively. The constructed "time series" would then be as follows (BMI values from above):

```
BMI  | V
25.3   1.1
25.4   2.2
24.1   3.3
22.9   1.1
22.1   2.2
21.1   3.3
```

A related question that I found (unfortunately it didn't give me all answers I was looking for):
[Are short time series worth modelling?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/are-short-time-series-worth-modelling)

Thanks in advance!