# How to forecast from longitudinal (panel) data

Tags: forecasting, panel-data

How is longitudinal forecasting usually done?

I know a bit about longitudinal (panel) data analyses, but I have not yet forecasted from longitudinal data.

I tend to think that building several time series forecasting models is a solution: since we have N subjects in longitudinal data, I think I need to build N forecasting models. Each one essentially becomes a time series forecasting model.

The problem is, usually, there are too few data measurements to build a performant forecasting model per subject.

Moreover, N can be quite large, so creating, updating, maintaining and using N forecasting models is tedious.

I am not sure if there is a way to create one forecasting model for all subjects - but I doubt this is effective.

Please advise.

Comment: What are your time series? "Panel data" suggests macroeconomics to me, in which case one would usually have recourse to vector autoregression (VAR)... but then you write about "subjects", which sounds like a different cup of tea. You might still be able to use a separate model per subject, though [that would likely be very simple models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/135061/1352), or you might use a "global" model, as used in the M4 or M5 forecasting competitions.

Comment: My panel data constitute a cohort of people being tracked over time, and I want to forecast a binary target variable to tell if a person is likely to become in a specific dire state or not. This is to accelerate help and provide support proactively to such people. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: It does, thank you. I would assume that you have (time-constant or time-varying) predictors per individual? My first impulse would be to fit a mixed GLM with a logistic family function, essentially a mixed logistic regression, with a random effect per ID, and with additional predictors (or a richer random effects structure) based on your specific dataset. Does that sound like an option?

Comment: It does sound like an option, thank you. I will give that a go and see how it goes.