# Machine learning method for predicting years ahead

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

Let's say I have Antarctic temperature data for 2020-2023, and based on this data I would like to forecast the temperature for the following years.

1. Which machine learning method will allow me to predict years ahead?
2. For what period forward could I generally forecast in order for the results to be satisfactory and probable?
3. Or should I collect data from the year 2000 onward and start building the model then?

**it would be great if you could recommend me a library for R with this method.*

Comment: Posted on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/123283/machine-learning-method-for-predicting-years-ahead.

Comment: 1. All else being equal, more data is better. 2. Why exactly are you attempting this? This is a problem for which we have better methods than just extrapolating from a time series - there are physical models that are used to predict future temperatures.

Answer (score 8):

- Three years of data is very little. You should not expect remarkable results when using such a small dataset, especially the farther ahead you are going to forecast. You could try using this data to make predictions maybe a few months ahead, not more than a year ahead. Twenty-three years of data would be much better (but see later paragraphs).
- If you really want to do it, with such a small dataset, you would [need to stick to simple forecasting models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135061/best-method-for-short-time-series), like the [naive method](https://otexts.com/fpp3/simple-methods.html), or assume linear trend (simple linear regression with time index as a feature). Black-box machine learning would simply overfit your data and be quite hopeless.
- However, as noticed in the comments, time-series forecasting is not the right tool for the job. We have good [physical climate models](https://www.climate.gov/maps-data/climate-data-primer/predicting-climate/climate-models) that are used for this purpose. If you are doing this for fun as an exercise to learn forecasting, feel free to do it, but if you need it for any serious purpose, you should stick to things that are known to work better.
- We know that climate changes could lead to [snowball effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_effect), where some changes provoke more changes, that provoke different changes, etc. The more ice melts, the warmer it is, the more ice melts, etc. This makes future weather harder to predict given the historical data. This year (2023) we already observed extreme heat waves breaking some historical records, as an example. All this may lead to changes that are exponential rather than linear in nature (recall the recent Covid-19 epidemic, which also grew exponentially) making it hard to predict. As an example, see the temperature trends, where the year 2023 is a clear outlier--you can clearly see that historical data does not tell us much to make further predictions.

[image: North Atlantic sea surface temperature, where the year 2023 is a clear outlier as compared to historical data since 1982.]